# is it possible to call command belonging to another container in docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, volumes

Is it possible to call a command inside docker which belongs to another container.

An example would be:

php container which contains php
app container which contains nginx

I would like to somehow share the php executable inside the nginx container.

Currently I have tried sharing the volumes with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: No; containers are isolated from each other and one container can't directly run a binary in another.  While the question I linked to mentions some very specific tools, its answer goes through the possible solutions.  In this particular case, running PHP-FPM in a separate container and using nginx's `fastcgi_pass` directive to forward requests to it is probably the best practice.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I got the clarification I needed.